# Asserter returning more than one element

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, assertions

I am trying to make a method that returns at the same time, two elements. This is my code:

```
 this.Wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.Id("mm_date_8")));
 this.Wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.Id("dd_date_8")));

 return this.Driver.FindElements(By.Id("mm_date_8"), By.Id("dd_date_8"));
```

But I don't know how to make it right...Can you please help me.
Thank you in advance!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if the following syntax is correct.

```
return this.Driver.FindElements(By.Id("mm_date_8"), By.Id("dd_date_8"));
```

instead what you can try to do is following.

```
List<IWebElement> elements = new List<IWebElement>();
AddElementsToList(elements, this.Driver.FindElements(By.Id("mm_date_8"));
AddElementsToList(elements, this.Driver.FindElements(By.Id("dd_date_8"));
// now in your calling method you can easily index list.
return elements;

public void AddElementsToList(List<IWebElement> elementList, IEnumerable<IWebElement> elementEnumerable)
{
    if (elementEnumerable != null && elementEnumerable.Any())
    {
        elementList.AddRange(elementEnumerable);
    }
}
```

Please note, I am assuming output of `FindElements` is `IEnumerable`. But if its other type of collection, the idea still remains the same.

If you must know what element belongs to what ID you can instead of creating a list can create a

```
Dictionary<string, IWebElement>
```

where string would be your `idKey`.